# Inheriting Comparable with generics

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Trying to design a superclass that ensures all sub-classes are inherently `Comparable`.

```
/**
 * A base class implementing Comparable with itself by delegation.
 * @param <T> - The type being wrapped.
 */
static class Distinct<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Distinct<T>> {
    final T it;
    public Distinct(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Distinct<T> o) {
        return it.compareTo(o.it);
    }
}
/**
 * A set of distinct items.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
static class ThingHolder<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    final Set<T> things;
    public ThingHolder() {
        this.things = new TreeSet<>();
    }
}
/**
 * A sample real thing.
 */
static class Thing extends Distinct<String> {
    public Thing(String it) {
        super(it);
    }
}
// This doesn't work - Why?
final ThingHolder<Thing> yz = new ThingHolder<>();
```

The error I get reads:

```
com/oldcurmudgeon/test/Test.java:[70,22] error: type argument Thing is not within bounds of type-variable T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class ThingHolder
```

Why is this not working? Can it be done?

Comment: I think `static class Distinct<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Distinct<T>> ` should be `static class Distinct<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<T>`

Comment: @bigdestroyer - BUt that - in my case - would be `implements Comparable<String>`, I want to compare them with each other, not with the generic type.

Comment: Nice puzzle about java type variables :)

Comment: `static class ThingHolder<T> { final Set<Comparable<T>> things;...` compiles but I've yet to figure out whether it does what it should. Update: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @biziclop - That's an option but it would leave the `Comparable` contract to run-time - which may not be the best option.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes, I'm just thinking aloud.

Comment: Your `Distinct` class declaration basically says that any subclass of `Distinct` is comparable to any other subclass of `Distinct`. That doesn't sound correct to me, and it's at the heart of the problem. `Thing implements Comparable<Distinct<Thing>>`, not `Comparable<Thing>`.

Comment: @biziclop - Surely that would be the case if I used `implements Comparable<Distinct<?>>` - I am using `implements Comparable<Distinct<T>>` suggesting it is comparable with objects of the same class only - or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm struggling to explain it, you can try to replace `T` with `String` across the board to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you pass a type argument `X` to `ThingHolder` it has to be a subtype of `Comparable<X>` (by the class declaration of `ThingHolder`).
2. So, if you pass the type `Thing` to `ThingHolder` it has to be a subtype of `Comparable<Thing>`. (Follows from the previous statement by substitution of `Thing` for `X`.)
3. `Thing` extends `Distinct<String>` and therefore implements `Comparable<Distinct<String>>` (by the class declaration of `Thing`).
4. `Thing` is not the same type as `Distinct<String>` - although it's a subtype - and therefore type matching fails.

You could fix this by adjusting the class declaration of `ThingHolder` as follows:

```
class ThingHolder<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Self-bounded type parameters do work in general though.

Comment: I accept that weakening the contract a little avoids the problem - like @Andremoniy suggested using `extends Comparable` but that still does not explain why the full strength contract does not work.

Comment: My explanation made no sense, sorry. I fixed the answer.

Comment: But `Distinct<T>` implements `Comparable<Distinct<T>>` and therefore should match the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` of `ThingHolder` - yet it does not.

Comment: I see you adopted my answer... The need to use ``<THIS_TYPE>`` constraints are always the cause of bad design; there must be a better solution for what you are trying.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon No, unfortunately that's not true. The Liskov substitution principle holds for objects (based on their type), but _doesn't_ hold for types themselves. This is a super confusing thing about type parameters, I know. Use `extends` and `super` to get similar behavior. See my updated answer.

Comment: I got there by a different route but essentially this is the best solution - although it may not be perfect as I note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some research and head-bashing brought up [this suggestion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html).

> In general, if you have an API that only uses a type parameter T as an argument, its uses should take advantage of lower bounded wildcards (? super T).

Some tinkering (adding `? super T`) to slightly relax the restrictions leaves:

```
/**
 * A set of distinct items.
 *
 * Don't like the <?> in there but a <T> is not accepted.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
static class ThingHolder<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    final Set<T> things = new TreeSet<>();

}

final ThingHolder<Thing> holder = new ThingHolder<>();
```

and this is acceptable to the compiler.

Generally I don't like using `?` to paper over the gaps because it usually allows too much through but in this case I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `ThingHolder` class signature to:

```
static class ThingHolder<T extends Comparable> {
       ...    
}
```

I.e. remove `<T>` from `Comparable`, it isn't necessary.

Comment: That seems to get around the problem - but why? This feels like using raw types as comparable is defined as `Interface Comparable<T>`.

Comment: I think there is some littel confusion here. Type variables are only some kind of restriction for compile time. They aren't anything existent. So, in your case with class `ThingHolder` you only declare that `T` should be `Comparable`, and it doesn't make sence for it - be comparable with it self, because it is implicitly so.

Comment: @Andremoniy You can always declare `class Foo implements Comparable<String>`, which is of course stupid, but valid. On the other hand you can say it isn't `Distinct`'s responsibility to handle such pointless class declarations.

Comment: Yes, but in this case `Distinct<String>`, not `Distinct<Disctinct>`.

Answer (score 0):

`class ThingHolder<T extends Comparable<T>>` declares that the *thing* `T` must be comparable to itself, but `class Thing extends Distinct<String>` isn't.

Comment: But `class Thing extends Distinct<String>` should inherit `Comparable<Distinct<String>>` shouldn't it?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes it does, but self-comparability requires ``Thing`` to be be comparable to ``Thing``, not ``String`` (via ``extends Distinct<String>``)